# how will the distribution of the no. of particles be in a system ,(N,V,E) if N tends to infinity?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

MB distribution is followed if there are N no. of non interacting and distinguishable particles. But if N tends to infinity why does the no. of micro states reduces?
Is there any peak in the graph?

Comment: The average energy per particle is $E/N$. So $N\to\infty$ effectively reduces the temperature of the system towards zero...

Comment: @lemon,ok But how will the distribution look like?